# Как узнать права на папку, файл?

Tags: python

Как узнать доступен ли файл, папка на чтение, запись, запуск? И если скрипт запущен от рута, как перезапустить его от юзера?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Чтобы получить ответ на первый вопрос попробуйте использовать функцию [os.access](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#files-and-directories)

```
import os
if os.access("/path/to/file", os.R_OK):
    print "have read access"
if os.access("/path/to/file", os.W_OK):
    print "have write access"
if os.access("/path/to/file", os.X_OK):
    print "can execute"
```

Если скрипт запущен от рута, то os.geteud() вернет 0. Можно вместо перезапуска подменить euid на uid нужного пользователя:

```
import pwd
p = pwd.getpwnam("username")
os.seteuid(p.pw_uid)
```